# connect contact form to firebase-database using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code below in javascript I want to make the contact form stored in firebase.

```
import { initializeApp } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.0/firebase-app.js'

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: '',

  authDomain: '',

  databaseURL: '',

  projectId: '',

  storageBucket: '',

  messagingSenderId: '',

  appId: '',
}

// Initialize Firebase

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

//reference messages collection
const messageRef = firebase.databaseURL().ref('messages')

//Listen for form submit
document.getElementById('contactForm').addEventListener('submit', submitForm)

function submitForm(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  // Get Values
  const name = getInputVal('yourName')
  const gender = getInputVal('gender')
  const message = getInputVal('input-area2')

  saveMessage(name, gender, message)
}
// function to get form values
function getInputVal(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id).value
}

// save the message to firebase

function saveMessage(name, gender, message) {
  const newMessageRef = messageRef.push()
  newMessageRef.set({
    name: name,
    gender: gender,
    message: message,
  })
}
```

and here is the HTML.

```
<section class="row get-in-touch-row" id="contact">
      <div
        class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 col-xxl-12 text-center align-self-center get-in-touch-info"
      >
        <h2>get in touch</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt
          quisquam, temporibus suscipit totam soluta tenetur beatae ea non eum!
          Quisquam!
        </p>
        <form action="" id="contactForm">
          <input
            class="input-area1"
            id="yourName"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Your Name"
            required
          />
          <input
            class="input-area1"
            id="gender"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Gender"
            required
          />
          <textarea
            name=""
            id="input-area2"
            cols="10"
            rows="10"
            placeholder="Message"
          ></textarea>
          <button type="submit">SEND MESSAGE</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </section>

<script src="index-script.js"></script>
    <script src="index-script2.js" type="module"></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
```

as you can see the form is one section on my website the javascript code above goes under index-script2 the error given to me is that firebase is not defined. any help what can I do to fix it and make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Your error 'firebase not defined' must be coming from the only place you're calling `firebase`, which is:

```
//reference messages collection
const messageRef = firebase.databaseURL().ref('messages')
```

Firebase version 9 uses modular syntax which substitutes the `firebase.someMethod()` syntax with free functions `someMethod()`

> In version 9, the firebase/app package and other packages do not
> return a comprehensive export that contains all the methods from the
> package. Instead, the packages export individual functions.

Documentation:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade

Example of how database is initialized:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getDatabase } from "firebase/database";

// TODO: Replace the following with your app's Firebase project configuration
// See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/learn-more#config-object
const firebaseConfig = {
  // ...
  // The value of `databaseURL` depends on the location of the database
  databaseURL: "https://DATABASE_NAME.firebaseio.com",
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);


// Initialize Realtime Database and get a reference to the service
const database = getDatabase(app);
```

Try writing your firebase initialization code and saveMessage() method like this:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getDatabase } from "firebase/database";

const firebaseConfig = {
  // ...
  // The value of `databaseURL` depends on the location of the database
  databaseURL: "https://DATABASE_NAME.firebaseio.com",
};

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Initialize Realtime Database and get a reference to the service
const database = getDatabase(firebaseApp);

function saveMessage(name, gender, message) {
  const newMessageRef = ref(database, 'messages'), {
    name: name,
    gender: gender,
    message: message,
  }
  
  set(newMessageRef);
}
```

Of course, make sure your HTML and form submission code is working without errors before attempting to write the data.

Comment: ok can u tell me how to do it exactly

Comment: updated answer - give that a try